# pixel coordinates to 3D

Tags: opencv, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a stereo camera mounted in a UR5 and I want to detect the holes of a work piece and move the tcp near the holes.
I detect the centre of the holes with opencv and but I don't know how to extract this info to 3D coordinates. I'm using opencv to solve this problem but I don't know how to solve it.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200613/pixel-coordinates-to-3d/) by [rcj1986](https://answers.ros.org/users/14706/rcj1986/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2015-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're detecting the center of the hole in both images, you can draw a ray from each camera through the hole based on which pixel the hole corresponds to and the image distortion model. Then you can find where the two rays intersect to determine the 3D position of the hole. The [image_geometry](http://wiki.ros.org/image_geometry) library has tools to help out with these types of problems.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2015-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rcj1986](https://answers.ros.org/users/14706/rcj1986/) on 2015-01-12**:
Thanks, I'll take a look.